# Is the version of Madoka Magica on Crunchyroll the DVD version?

Tags: madoka-magica, crunchyroll

The DVD version has various changes (animation improvements, etc). I don't believe Madoka was on Crunchyroll during airing, so is the stream from the DVD edition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See below for some comparison screenshots from episode 2, at the beginning of the first scene on the school roof (the one where Homura comes and gives a mysterious warning to Madoka and Sayaka).

Judging from the railings surrounding the roof area and the floor tiles, Crunchyroll is using the **Blu-Ray/DVD** version of *Madoka Magica*. Not the TV version.

---

**TV**

[image: Madoka and Sayaka on the roof, TV version]

**Blu-Ray**

[image: Madoka and Sayaka on the roof, BD version]

**Crunchyroll**

[image: Madoka and Sayaka on the roof, Crunchyroll version]